# How to reorder or rearrange h3 tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Trying to rearrange the order of h3 tags using jQuery.
For every h3 tag we have div tag on expanding h3.
So, here am able to rearrange h3 tags but not its sibblings i.e div tags.

Could any one please suggest me any changes in my script or any other approach.

Below is my Example:

```
<script>
$("#mainDivId").accordion();
function dragAndDrop(){
    jQuery('#mainDivId').sortable({
        update : function(event, ui) {
            var x = ui['item'].parent().children().map(function() {             
                return $(this).attr("index");               
            }).get().join(",");

        }
    }); 

}
jQuery(function() {
    dragAndDrop();  
});
</script>

<div id="mainDivId">
<h3 index="0">
    h3-0
</h3>
<div index="0">
    div-0
</div>
<h3 index="1">
    h3-1
</h3>
<div index="1">
    div-1
</div>
<h3 index="2">
    h3-2
</h3>
<div index="2">
    div-2
</div>
<h3 index="3">
    h3-3
</h3>
<div index="3">
    div-3
</div>
<h3 index="4">
    h3-4
</h3>
<div index="4">
    div-4
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In sortable you can specify what elements it affects - http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

Answer (score 2):

You can add a wrapper to all the h3 and div pair. What's happening in above code is that only h3 elements are being dragged leaving corresponding content in it's original place. Here's working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/javedsaifi/wtoqa412/

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainDivId").accordion({
        header: "> div > h3"
    }).sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
            $(this).accordion("refresh");
        }
    });
});
<div id="mainDivId">
    <div class="group">
         <h3 index="0"> h3-0 </h3>
        <div index="0">div-0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
         <h3 index="1"> h3-1 </h3>
        <div index="1">div-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
         <h3 index="2"> h3-2 </h3>
        <div index="2">div-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
         <h3 index="3"> h3-3 </h3>
        <div index="3">div-3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
         <h3 index="4"> h3-4 </h3>
        <div index="4">div-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible could you please provide me a solution without wrapper, because we are using primefaces accordian which generates above html automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the dom generates automatically, then you can add the wrapper div form jquery as well. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javedsaifi/3Lfj40om/

```
$(function(){
    $('#mainDivId > h3').each(function () {
        $(this).next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="group">');
    });
    $("#mainDivId").accordion({
        header: "> div > h3"
    }).sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
            $(this).accordion("refresh");
        }
    });        
});
<div id="mainDivId">
  <h3 index="0"> h3-0 </h3>
  <div index="0"> div-0</div>
  <h3 index="1"> h3-1 </h3>
  <div index="1"> div-1 </div>
  <h3 index="2"> h3-2 </h3>
  <div index="2"> div-2 </div>
  <h3 index="3"> h3-3 </h3>
  <div index="3"> div-3 </div>
  <h3 index="4"> h3-4 </h3>
  <div index="4"> div-4 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If we add wrapper dynamically, primefaces accordian component gets disturbed, can we reorder/rearrange without disturbing the existing DOM.